# Im need some kinda help..... a script..... that can do the following

Tags: tcl

suppose i input a pattern like AAAABBCCC .....

then the script should print like T1 0 A-4 B-2 C-3 0 T1

where T1 is tap and 0 indicates next line......

if patern is like AAABBCC 
                  CABCCBA

then the script should generate a pattern T1 0 A-3 B-2 C-2 0 T1 
                                           0 C A B  C-2 B A 0 T1   # should start with T1 and end with T1.... and only one T1 is allowed in between patterns......
Im new to TCL, please help.....

Answer (score 3):

```
set pattern1 {AAAABBCCC}
set pattern2 {AAABBCC
CABCCBA}

proc process {pattern} {
    lappend result "T1"
    foreach line [split $pattern "\n"] {
        lappend result "0"
        foreach {chunk symbol} [regexp -all -inline {(.)(?:\1+)?} $line] {
            set num [string length $chunk]
            lappend result $symbol[expr {($num>1)?"-$num":""}]
        }
        lappend result "0" "T1" "\n"
    }
    return [join $result]
}

puts [process $pattern1]
puts [process $pattern2]
```

The output of the code above:

```
T1 0 A-4 B-2 C-3 0 T1

T1 0 A-3 B-2 C-2 0 T1
 0 C A B C-2 B A 0 T1
```

Comment: Hi GrAnd: if I have a file of only two lines wer in Ive a variable likr mul = 64 and in the same line there is anoy=ther variable a which indicates that a has to be multiplied 64 times...... ie A-64....similarly next line has B and mul = 32 indicating B-32....how can this be done......

Comment: Sorry, do not understand you. It seems unrelated to my answer. Anyway, make a minimal effort and do something by yourself. If you stuck, show us your code and the community will try to help. This site is not the right place to ask for full solutions from scratch (for your labs?).